# Citing a Children's Book in APA 7

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style, apa7

I'm new to LaTeX, currently using Overleaf to write an academic paper for school, APA 7 format.

I'm attempting to reference *Charlie and the Great Glass Elevator* by Roald Dahl.
The APA website says:

a) the illustrator must also be included, and

b) classic books that have been republished must have both publication dates in the reference.

**link to APA webpage:
https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/childrens-book-references

Any insight into how to format the bibtex code to achieve the APA 7 reference format would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of a BibTeX bibliography style that implements the APA7 guidelines. (The `apacite` bib style and eponymous citation management pakage implement the APA6 guidelines.) To implement the APA7 guidelines, you'll need to employ biblatex and biber.

Comment: Thank you. I just read over the package documentation for apa 7 on CTAN, and you're correct. https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7?lang=en